# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows )shows for a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01422

I have tired to create a trigger like this,
but it shows this error

Comment: This error indicates that your query `SELECT DNAME INTO DeptName ...` returns more than one record. How do you want to handle this case?

Comment: I was trying to check to see if the purchase is handled by department 'SALES - Sunshine'. if the employee in new row is working in 'SALES - Sunshine' then do the following

Comment: Is it possible that an employee works in more than one department?

Comment: No. The employee works in only one dept

Comment: You can't query `PURCHASE` within a row-level trigger on `PURCHASE`, so I'm not sure why you aren't getting a mutating table error. I suspect `INNER JOIN PURCHASE ON` should just be `where`.

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL has an assignment operator `:=` which you can use to assign values to variables without needing a query, e.g. `:new.paymenttype := 'Cash';`

Comment: Instead of `SELECT 'Cash' INTO :NEW.PAYMENTTYPE FROM DUAL; ` simply write `:NEW.PAYMENTTYPE := 'Cash'; `

Comment: @WilliamRobertson you are right, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that your query `SELECT DNAME INTO DeptName ...` returns more than one record, hence its result cannot be assigned to a scalar variable. The problem with your query is that you have an unecessary `JOIN` on `purchase`, so it returns one record for each sale performed by the employee that just did the current sale.

I believe that your query can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT d.dname INTO DeptName
FROM emp e
INNER JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno
WHERE e.empno = :NEW.servedby;
```